# How to choose one field from one retrieved row in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    if ($this->request->data) {
        $query = $users->findByEmail($this->request->getData('email'));
```

In the code above, I have retrieved one row from my table where the user's email matches the requested email.

Next, I want to write the code below to check if the password of the selected user is same as the requested password.

```
PasswordOfSelectedRow == md5($this->request->getData('password')))
```

What should I put instead of PasswordOfSelectedRow?

Comment: Why are you not using Auth component? What you are doing seems to easily introduce large security issues into the app.

Comment: @mark OK thanks for the tip, I will be looking more into Auth components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line returns a [query object from a dynamic finder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#dynamic-finders)

```
$query = $users->findByEmail($this->request->getData('email'));
```

From the docs:

> Once you have a query object from a dynamic finder, you’ll need to call first() if you want the first result.

So you could write something like this to retrieve the user:

```
$user = $query->first();
```

And then to compare to the request data:

```
$user->password == md5($this->request->getData('password')))
```

Comment: But for the sake of everything holy and sacred, please don't use MD5 hashed passwords!

Comment: @JAVAnewbie Because [**MD5 is very fast and cryptographically weak**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure). The MD5 algorithm's collision resistance has long been cracked (ie it's possible to generate the same hash for different input), and an average modern GPU can calculate billions of MD5 hashes per second, making bruteforce attacks extremely cheap, especially when no salt is being used, which also makes the hashes a good target for [**rainbow tables**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-are-rainbow-tables-and-how-are-they-used).

Comment: @JAVAnewbie When hasing passwords, always [**use an algorithm that is as expensive as possible**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords), for example bcrypt. [**CakePHP ships with a password hasher/validator**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords) that uses bcrypt by default.